# Is there a need to train the model first before K fold cross validation or after train the model?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am implementing a neural network for classification purpose and now i am in trouble of cross validation my question is given below :

Do we need to train the model first and then cross validate it (K fold) , or we first cross validate the model ,then pick that model which performs well on unseen data and then train it , Could anybody guide me that how this whole procedure runs , it is getting confused because if training's
done before or after then what is the role of that training part which is in K Fold ?
    Thanks in advance .

Answer (score -2):

The answer is yes.
After testing the model using K fold cross validation, it is recommended to train the model using whole data.

Comment: Ok , i got it and one more question that is there a need to train the model before Cross validation?

Comment: No. Cross validation is to test the model, not train the model. Check the classification or regression performance such as accuracy and MAE using cross validation, and then make final model if the performance satisfies you.

Comment: In addition, model is trained k times when using cross-validation, so you don't need to train the model in advance.

Comment: Why it is necessary to train the model after cross validation

Comment: When K-cross validation is used, K models are trained. So, if you want to use this model, then you should choose one of them. However, each model is trained with partial data (I mean k-1 folds) and thus re-training using whole data is more proper than choosing one of them.

Comment: OK @Gilseung Ahn , but we see the mean of accuracy in it , which fold should i pick from it either of the highest accuracy or which fold ?